# How to compare values and apply formatting when one cell is a formula?

Tags: microsoft-excel, conditional-formatting

I need to apply conditional formatting in one cell based on its comparison against another cell that is of a different format. For example; `Column A` contains cells with formula. `Column B` contains cells with values.

I want to compare `Row 1 Column A` against `Row 1 Column B` and fill the background of `Row 1 Column B` in red if it differs from `Row 1 Column A`.

How can I do this?

(Bear in mind that the first cell is a formula displaying a value, e.g., `="C1"` and the second cell is a value. So normal conditional formatting comparison `=$A1=$B1` will always be false even if `A1` display as "1" and cell `B1` is "1").

Comment: What do you mean with `="C1"` ?? Your scenario is not clear. Was that a typo? Does the cell contain a reference to C1 or the text string "C1" ?

Comment: @CharlieRB you edited the question and changed it to what you assume the cell content was. You cannot be sure that this is the case. I'm rolling this back.

Comment: This is a strange question. First, How can `A1` display `1` if the formula is `="C1"`? Second, the OP said "comparison against another cell that is of a different format" but did not tell what format it was. We need to _guess_ how things happen. _If_ the formula cell referred to a number and the the value cell were in text format, the comparison `=$A1=$B1` would return false, but using `=EXACT($A1,$B1)` or `=$A1&""=$B1&""` would solve this problem. However, we cannot be sure if it _is_ the problem unless the OP state clearly what format the cells has. So, what format are the cells?

Answer (score 1):

From a blank sheet:

```
In A1 enter =c1
In b1 enter 5
In c1 enter 5
```

Select b1, click conditional formatting in the ribbon, and New Rule
Click "use a formula to determine cells to format".

In the formula box type =$b$1=$a$1
Click the format button and change the color to red, Click ok

Click ok

Click ok

B1 should now have red text.  Change the value in c1 and the text will become black.

Comment: The OP stated *fill the background of Row 1 Column B in red if it differs from Row 1 Column A*. You need to correct your formula.